# python script not working after using pyinstaller to make it .exe

Tags: python

```
path = os.path.realpath(__file__)
try:
    shutil.move(path, "C:\\Users\\pc\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup")
except:
    pass  
try:
    if os.path.exists("C:\\Users\\pc\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\{}".format(os.path.basename(__file__))):
        os.remove(path)
except:
    pass
```

this whole block of my code in python doesn't work anymore after using pyinstaller, therefore doesn't move the file to the destination. keep in mind it worked just by running the python script, so how do i adapt it to use pyinstaller to make it an .exe file (a working one)

Comment: The easiest way (in my opinion) to figure out stuff like this is just put in a few print statements to see where the code gets to, and also print out the paths. I wouldn't be surprised if  `__file__` is a bit different to what you're expecting.

Comment: what exact pyinstaller command did you use? did you include all necessary libraries, etc.

Comment: yes, both os and shutlib libraries are imported

Comment: i used pyinstaller -F -w filename.py, that's why i can't use the solution print cz it's prevented with the command -w i think

Comment: If you can't `print` the values, then write them into a file. Or don't make the result a Windows app so `print` will work.

Answer (score 0):

`__file__` still points to the script's name, which is unzipped into a temporary directory.
PyInstaller as well as Py2exe are overwriting sys.executable to the application's path, for example: `C:\Programs\myApplication\app.exe`.

You might want to go through the [docs](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/runtime-information.html#using-sys-executable-and-sys-argv-0) for detailed information.